# Minimum number of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

For some integer $n$, consider $S=\{1, \dots, n\}$. Let $S_1, \dots, S_k$ be subsets that satisfy the property that each $x\in S$ is in exactly 3 of the $S_i$'s and so that the intersection of these three subsets is $x$. What is the minimum value of $k$ (the number of subsets)?

I thought that if each $x$ was in 2 of the sets, $k$ would be at least $2*\sqrt{n}$, but was not sure how to proceed for the case of 3 sets.

Comment: Are you only interested in a lower bound, or do you want the exact minimum (i.e: a construction)?

Comment: Have you found some sensible collection of $S_i$ that works?

Comment: Just to sate the obvious, if $N$ works then we must have $\binom N3≥n\implies N(N-1)(N-2)≥6n$ so you are looking at, roughly, $\sqrt[3]{6n}$.  Doesn't mean you can do it with that $N$; it's only a lower bound.

Comment: @Steven I would be very interested to see a construction—that's what I've been trying to do, but have gotten stuck with that.

Comment: The stated problem seems to be a special case of a generalisation of block-designs, so it seems unlikely that you find the actual lower bound for each $n$, but I could be wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I have updated this answer with a purely combinatorial description, since the original problem was combinatorial in flavor.*

Choose $k$ so as small as possible so that $\binom{k}3\ge n$. Identify the numbers $\{1,\dots,\binom{k}3\}$ with the subsets of $\{1,\dots,k\}$ of size $3$. Then, for each $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, let $S_i$ be the set of numbers in $\{1,\dots,n\}$ whose corresponding subset contains $i$. Clearly, any $x\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, corresponding to the set $\{i,j,h\}$, is contained in exactly three subsets $S_i,S_j,S_h$, and the intersection of these subsets is $x$.

This is optimal for the reason lulu said in a comment; in order for such a collection of sets to exist, you you need $\binom{k}3\ge n$. Asymptotically, we get $k\sim \sqrt[3]{6n}$.

This generalizes to any multiplicity of intersections. In particular, $2\sqrt{n}$ for the two-way intersection problem you mentioned is not optimal, and you can obtain $\sim\sqrt{2n}$ by letting $\{1,\dots,\binom{k}2\}$ correspond to pairs of numbers in $\{1,\dots,k\}$.

Comment: If $\binom{k}{3} > n$, then your sets $S_i$ are not necessarily subsets of $S$.

Comment: @Steven Indeed, I meant to restrict to $\{1,\dots,n\}$, and have made this change.

Comment: But now two subsets $S_i$ and $S_j$ could be the same, right? I don't know if that was allowed by the OP.

Comment: @Steven This cannot happen. If $S_i=S_j$, that would mean that every 3-subset represented by $\{1,\dots,n\}$ contains either both $i$ and $j$, or neither $i$ nor $j$, There are at most $\binom{k-3}3+\binom{k-2}1$ such subsets, but this is at most $\binom{k-1}3<n$ whenever $k\ge 5$ (which occurs whenever $n\ge5$, and you can check it works for $n=4$ directly. For $n\le 3$, you might need a different construction, but that's close to trivial.)

Comment: In my last comment, it should be $\binom{\color{green}{k-2}}3+\binom{k-2}1$ instead of $\binom{\color{red}{k-3}}3+\binom{k-2}1$

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you, this answer is wonderful!

Comment: @JosephRodriguez $|S_i|\le \binom{k-1}2$, as there are $\binom{k-1}2$ ways to choose the other two elements of the set.

Comment: @MikeEarnest if we impose the restriction that $|S_i|\leq \sqrt{n}$, what bound can we get on the value of $k$?

Comment: @JosephRodriguez No idea. It seems like that completely changes the question. You could post is as a separate question, and include a link to this one.

Answer (score -1):

This is the Fano plane:

[image]

How might this figure relate to the question?

Comment: Each point is on exactly three of the circles/lines? So if we think of each circle/line as a collection of the points it passes through, they give a valid set of subsets.

Comment: There are 3 points on each line.  We can relate the lines to the subsets of S.

Comment: This is just an example of order $n$=7, but the problem is *not* equivalent to finding projective planes, so it is unclear how to generalise this to higher $n$.

Comment: This isn't even optimal for $n=7$, since it is possible to get $6$ sets.